# Creating new accounts, logins glitch

Tags: support, login, linked-accounts, stack-exchange-openid

I have singed up to the French community, and I saw that I used my gmail login for it, not my OpenId login. To test this, I tried signing up to the German community, using my openId account, but I land on this:

[image]

I signed up, saw that it connected to my other accounts, but why isn't there a proposal for my openID account? i am logged in my openID in another tab!

Can this be caused by third party cookies that I have disactivated with extensions?

Answer (score 2):

You have both Google and Stack Exchange OpenID credentials attached to your account. Both will work to log you in.

That page just goes by whichever credential was most recently used.

Comment: if I want to connect with openID though

Comment: @FlipFloop It's still available. Credentials are attached to your overall network account, not individual site profiles. The text on the join page could use work to be more clear about what's actually happening.

Comment: Maybe make that text on the first line read: *....using a recent login from:*?  In my mind it sounded better :(

Comment: When I checked the OP profile earlier (shortly after the question was posted), the link to his [German.SE profile](http://german.stackexchange.com/users/20740/flipfloop) resulted in 404 error, so something there was weird/broken. Now it works though.